# convert points to svg path/file in java

Tags: java, svg, vaadin

I wrote a simple drawing application using vaadin, from my app I collect all the points coordinate which are generated by using moving mouse on a canvas. What is the best way to convert these points data into svg? Many thanks

Comment: I ve tried DOMparser, so far so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a line that follows the points, then create a path element line this:

```
<path d="Mx0 y0 Lx1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 ... Z"/>
```

Where x0, y0 etc. are the coordinates you have. The Z is optional; it creates a closed polygon by adding a straight line from the last point to the first, and lets you apply a fill style instead of just a line style.